# CMake Linker Error with CppUnit OS X 10.10

Tags: c++, cmake, osx-yosemite, cppunit

I'm having an issue with my CMake environment.
My team uses CppUnit, however our test build has been failing ever since upgrading to OS X 10.10 (Yosemite)
This build works on Linux machines and OS X Mavericks.
We are at a loss as to why it is not working.

Our CMakeLists.txt can be found here: https://gist.github.com/VikomMedia/802fb41a411dd2f7358e

```
...
Linking CXX executable sailbot_test
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "SailingLogicTest::testShouldBeat()", referenced from:
      SailingLogicTest::addTestsToSuite(CppUnit::TestSuiteBuilderContextBase&) in SailingLogicTest.cpp.o
  "SailingLogicTest::testIsThereChangeToAWA()", referenced from:
      SailingLogicTest::addTestsToSuite(CppUnit::TestSuiteBuilderContextBase&) in SailingLogicTest.cpp.o
  "SailingLogicTest::testCanReachDestWithoutTack()", referenced from:
      SailingLogicTest::addTestsToSuite(CppUnit::TestSuiteBuilderContextBase&) in SailingLogicTest.cpp.o
  "SailingLogicTest::testIsThereChangeToAWAorBearing()", referenced from:
      SailingLogicTest::addTestsToSuite(CppUnit::TestSuiteBuilderContextBase&) in SailingLogicTest.cpp.o
  "CppUnit::SourceLine::SourceLine(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int)", referenced from:
      SailingLogicTest::testArrivedAtDest() in SailingLogicTest.cpp.o
      SailingLogicTest::testGetBearing() in SailingLogicTest.cpp.o
...
```

The full log can be found here: https://gist.github.com/VikomMedia/71ee83dcd6f7b538a343

The result is identical with -stdlib=libc++ and -stdlib=libstdc++

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were able to solve the issue by changing the compiler to G++ on OS X 10.10 machines.  clang++ was not working, the reason is unknown at this time.

Comment: I know this is pretty old, but, in case someone finds this ... it looks like `clang` is compiling/linking using `std::__1::basic_string` (and others), which I think is normal.  But maybe `cppunit` was built/linked using `std::basic_string`, and the `clang` linker isn't looking for that.  Unfortunately, I'm not sure if there is an easy fix.  I know `g++` has linker options like `--no-as-needed` which can adjust what is happening during linking.  But I don't know the linking options in `clang` well enough to provide any suggestions.  Hope this points someone in the right direction.